# Calculating calories with the Lifelog API

Tags: sony-lifelog-api

I have actual data coming in from the Lifelog API now in the below format

```
{
   "result" : [
  ...
  {
     "id" : "ba2e7500-e022-4daf-817b-1e607e0cff43",
     "type" : "physical",
     "subtype" : "walk",
     "sources" : [
        {
           "name" : "abc123",
           "id" : "42ad35b065e880a3",
           "type" : "phone"
        }
     ],
     "startTime" : "2014-06-09T10:54:00.000+01:00",
     "endTime" : "2014-06-09T10:57:00.000+01:00",
     "details" : {
        "steps" : [ 20, 28, 19 ],
        "distance" : [ 13.662, 19.1268, 12.9789 ],
        "aee" : [ 2.1361, 2.1361, 2.1361 ],
        "tee" : [ 3.1361, 3.1361, 3.1361 ]
     }
  }
  ...
  ]
}
```

This is great but what I want is to calculate calories. How do I do this with the API?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sony expert, I'm just trying to find out more about their apis.
Here is what I've read so far and may be helpful to you.

#### aee

> Active Energy Expenditure(AEE), an array of KCAL values, recorded for each minute in this time period. This represents energy burned above the user’s BMR.

#### tee

> Total Energy Expenditure(TEE). An array of KCAL values, recorded for each minute in this time period. This represents energy burned including the user’s BMR.

[Sony API reference (available until May 2017)](http://web.archive.org/web/20160325214936/https://developer.sony.com/develop/services/lifelog-api/guides/how-to-calculate-calories)

So according to these your total calories consumption was `3.1361 + 3.1361 + 3.1361 ~= 9.4 kcal` in that three minutes.

Without BMR `2.1361 + 2.1361 + 2.1361 ~= 6.4 kcal`.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I actually was given this equation to get total calories with BMR: totalCalories = totalAEE + (bmr * hoursSinceMidnight);

Answer (score 1):

So now there is actually an online guide showing how to do calorie calculation:

http://web.archive.org/web/20160325214936/https://developer.sony.com/develop/services/lifelog-api/guides/how-to-calculate-calories/ (available until May 2017)